# Getting error in trying to setup Cordova for the Android Platform

Tags: android, cordova

I have installed the latest version of Android Studio on windows platform and when running:

```
cordova requirements
```

I get the error:

```
Java JDK: installed 11.0.20
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed
Command failed with exit code 1: avdmanager list target
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.run(AvdManagerCli.java:213)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.main(AvdManagerCli.java:200)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 5 more
Gradle: installed C:\Gradle\gradle-8.3\bin\gradle.BAT
```

- Cordova version is 12.0.0
- Java version is 11.0.20
- Multiple jdk is not installed

In Android Studio SDK Manager Android 12.0 API Level 31 is installed and
Device Emulator is Pixel XL API 31

Following Environmental Variable are included:

JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11

ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\skd\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = C:\Users\skd\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

PATH:

%JAVA_HOME%\bin

C:\Gradle\gradle-8.3\bin

%ANDROID_HOME%\emulator

%ANDROID_HOME%\tools

%ANDROID_HOME%\tools\bin

%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools

%ANDROID_HOME%\cmdline-tools\latest\bin

The following sdk tools are installed in android studio:

- Android SDK Build Tools - version 34
- Android SDK Command Line Tools Latest
- Android Emulator
- Android SDK Platform Tools

The emulator runs fine. I have also tried many ideas in different Stack Overflow articles regarding this.

Comment: You need to install SDK 33

Comment: Just installed SDK 33 (Tiramisu), same result

Comment: The test project runs just fine on the emulator though!